# CanJS - Incorrect list objects type after mapping

Tags: reactjs, canjs, donejs

If I have this instantiation `const someObj = new MyObj({...someParams})` and `MyObj` is defined this way:

```
MyObj = DefineMap.extend("MyObj", {
  myProp: {
    Type: AnotherType.List
  }
})
```

and

```
AnotherType.List = CanList.extend("AnotherType.List", {
  Map: AnotherType
}, {
  serialize() {
    const res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.attr("length"); i++) {
      res.push(this.attr(i.toString()).serialize());
    }
    return res;
  }
})
```

then the `someObj.myProp[0]` type is `DefineMap` instead of `AnotherType`. How can I fix this?

I already tried this but still not working: `const someObj = canReflect.assignDeep(new MyObj(), {...someParams})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Bitovi community](https://bitovi-community.slack.com/archives/CFC22NZ8A/p1652724173578839) I solved it (thanks to Brad Momberger).

So Brad explained that it happens because of the `DefineList`'s bubble binding and the same doesn't happen with `DefineMap` objects.

So we always need to serialize the lists first the get the correct type of the list entries at the end, like this:

```
const someObj = new MyObj({
  ...someParams,
  myProp: someParams.myProp.serialize()
})
```

You can see the full explanation [here](https://bitovi-community.slack.com/archives/CFC22NZ8A/p1652724173578839).

Comment: Hey that's me!  I wanted to clarify that bubble bindings are a feature of Can.List and Can.Map (the "change" event fired on a property update "bubbles up" to Maps and Lists that contain the object with the property update).  DefineList and DefineMap do not have bubble bindings.